# Svn how to checkin using different level of commit message

Tags: svn

I have a case where different commit log template has been used in the subdirectorectory. So during a single commit, i am only allow to use the commit log template from the folder that is selected.

I would like to know if it possible to save different commit message for each specific subdirectory in a single checkin action